# Wordpress and crontab

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, cron

I have built a Wordpress plugin that polls an api, this api along with other data, returns URLs to images (the user polling the api owns these images). Moving the images from the api server to my server is time consuming but needs to be done as we want Wordpress to create multiple sizes of the images - thus we need to utilise it's upload functionality. Sometimes the data may return 500+ results each result could multiple images.

I am wanting to offset the image retrieval into a daily CRON job, however I cannot seem to get the cron to run, I have done the following in my code,

**wp-config.php**

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

I register a scheduled event in my plugin code like this,

```
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'process_images_hourly' );
```

This theoretically should put this function (below) into a job list.

```
    function process_images_hourly()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_autotrader_image_process WHERE process_status = 'Unprocessed';");
    $processed_id = [];
    foreach($results as $result) {
        if(isset($result->image_url)) {

            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $attachment_array = [];
            if( !class_exists( 'WP_Http' ) ) {
                include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-http.php' );
            }
            $http = new WP_Http();
            $file = file_get_contents($result->image_url);
            $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            $ext = $finfo->buffer($file);
            if(strpos($ext, 'jpeg') || strpos($ext, 'jpg')) {
                $type = '.jpg';
            } elseif(strpos($ext, 'png')) {
                $type = '.png';
            } elseif(strpos($ext, 'gif')) {
                $type = '.gif';
            }
            $response = $http->request( $result->image_url );
            //die(print_r($image['secure']['href']));
            if( $response['response']['code'] != 200 ) {
                die(print_r($response['response']));
                return false;
            }

            $upload = wp_upload_bits( basename($result->image_url), null, $response['body'] );

            if( !empty( $upload['error'] ) ) {
                die(print_r($upload));
                return false;
            }

            $file_path = $upload['file'];

            $file_name = basename( $file_path );
            $file_type = wp_check_filetype( $file_name );
            $attachment_title = sanitize_file_name( pathinfo( $file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME ) );
            $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

            $post_info = array(
                'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . $file_name . $type,
                'post_mime_type' => $finfo->buffer($file),
                'post_title'     => $attachment_title,
                'post_content'   => '',
                'post_status'    => 'inherit',
            );

            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $post_info, $file_path );
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file_path );
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
            $attachment_array[] = $attach_id;
            update_field( 'gallery', $attachment_array , $result->post_id );
            $wpdb->delete( 'wp_autotrader_image_process', array( 'id' => $result->id ));
        }

    }

}
```

I then have cronjob on my server that does this,

```
*/15 * * * * curl https://Xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.com/wp-cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This runs the wp-cron file every fifteen minutes.

However I don't think my function is running, can anyone explain to why, or how set this up properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add this code:

```
add_action( 'call_process_images_hourly', 'process_images_hourly' );
```

and update:

```
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'call_process_images_hourly' );
```